# Data validation, less than or equal - based on the data from other sheet

Tags: excel, invoice

I have a task to create an invoice with automatic data-fill in some cells, based on the data from other sheet. Then, there is a discount cell - which has to be validated with maximum value from other sheet.
So, the first part is solved with Validation-List, linked to other sheet and with the following formula to get auto description and price from that other sheet

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A11);"";VLOOKUP($A11;items!A:C;2;))
```

List1 - https://i.ibb.co/f9Y3WQB/LIST2.jpg

List2 - https://i.ibb.co/kS1jR9y/LIST2.jpg

Referring to pictures - the customer is putting his value into "`Discount`" field, which has to be validated with "`Less or equal`" from "`Maximum discount allowed`" from the second sheet. If the entered value is greater - the error message shall be shown.

Got any suggestions how that's done?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it: In data validation for cell E11 choose "Custom" and enter the following formula:

```
=E11<=VLOOKUP(B11;items!$B$2:$D$10;3;0)
```

Then copy the cell E11 to all the other cells you need to have the data validation.

Comment: Maybe try this:
    =E11<=VLOOKUP(B11;items!$B$2:$D$10;3;0)
This looks for an exact match.
If the problem is solved please consider accepting the answer, so the question is closed.

Comment: @EileanNordsey Please consider marking the question as answered if this solved your problem. (Checkmark to the left of the answer)

Comment: Yep, exact match fixed the thing. Now it's all correct and working. Thank you so much!!